# InteractiveBarChart: how to bind model data?

Tags: sapui5

I can't find any example about binding a JSON model to the control [`sap.suite.ui.microchart.InteractiveBarChart`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.microchart.InteractiveBarChart) in an XML view.

My view is the following:

```xml
<mc:InteractiveBarChart xmlns:mc="sap.suite.ui.microchart"
  labelWidth="25%"
  bindBars="{/}"
>
  <mc:bars>
    <mc:InteractiveBarChartBar label="{key}" value="{value}" />
  </mc:bars>
</mc:InteractiveBarChart>
```

I've to bind the `InteractiveBarChart` to my model. An array is set in the controller. By API reference, I've to use `bindBars` method, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any control in UI5 has the same concepts of [data binding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c): *property* and *aggregation* bindings.

If control is aimed to show multiple things (i.e. table or list), it will have the so called [aggregation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/overview).

In *InteractiveBarChart* control there is an aggregation "[bars](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.microchart.InteractiveBarChart/aggregations)".

Any control can be bound against model via the unified [binding syntax](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/e2e6f4127fe4450ab3cf1339c42ee832).

- For programmatic binding is the following template: "bind{NAME OF AGGREGATION}". So in this case it will be "*bindBars*" method, which takes the same list of arguments as any aggregation binding;
- For declaration binding in XML, you have to do 2 things:

  1. tell the control about data source. In your case you should set the control's property with the name of aggregation "*bars*" to the binding string "*{/}*", in case you store the raw array in the root property of a default model (i.e. model without name)
  2. define a template, which will be used as a basis of creation of a list of bars (you've already done it correctly)

Comment: Just another question: if i use a model with name (ie "docNum"), where i have to set it in the xml view? I've tried inside tag 'binding', 'bars', without luck

Comment: you have to tell the view about existence of this model by doing the following in controller: this.getView().setModel(oModel, "docNum") and use the model name in your bindings. In your case the binding will look like this: "{docNum>/}". Please refer to documentation articles, there is a good explanation of all these binding stuff, which are the core of the framework in my opinion.